# Apache 2.4, basic file authentication ignored

Tags: apache-httpd, authentication

I have the following in my (Debian-style, split-file) config

```
<VirtualHost *>
ServerName www.example.org
DocumentRoot /var/www/example
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/example/access.log combined

<Directory /var/www/example/subdir/admin/>
   AllowOverride All
   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "admins only"
   AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/pass.txt
   Require valid-user
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

And it's ignored, i.e. I can browse files in that directory, no login prompt.
I've set `LogLevel debug` and I see

```
AH01628: authorization result: granted (no directives)
```

The log line is created by `[authz_core:debug]` so it seems to recognize the auth lines are there, just not that it needs to actually do some authorisation.

Even replacing `valid-user` with `all denied` has no effect.

I seem to have all the modules I need.

I tried adding a `.htaccess` in another directory and that logged "AuthType not allowed here".

I have `AllowOverride All` just about everywhere it's allowed.

Similar questions have not come up with a solution that works for me.  Please tell me how to troubleshoot this and I'll be happy to try it and report back.

Comment: I wouldn't allow any htaccess stuff inside a protected directory (i.e. set `AllowOverride None`), the rest looks okay to me. Did you reload/restart your server?

Comment: Are you definitely accessing the directory through the expected vhost? (www.example.org in your example configuration snippet) Are you sure there isn't another vhost referencing the same directory tree but without access control?

Comment: Freddy, the AllowOverrides are temporary, will all be removed except where needed.

Comment: Roaima, there's a top-level vhost with "Require all granted" and one for the domain.  This is meant to reduce access for this subfolder.

Comment: This vhost is ignored if the other vhost matches. Are you sure your content is served (and logged) from this vhost?

Comment: It's certainly using this vhost as it maps the domain to its own root dir.  But there is a vhost that maps "/" to the top docroot.  Could any directives in that affect the domain vhost?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a definitive answer but I can report how I fixed it.

All http requests were redirected to https, though I'm not clear where that was done.  This meant that the vhosts for *:80 were ignored and the *:443 ones were the ones used.  I moved the auth stuff to the *:443 vhost and preceded it with a "Require all denied" and it now requests the login.  Here's the code as included in the vhost

```
<Directory /subdir/>
   Require all denied
</Directory>

<Location /subdir/>
   AllowOverride All
   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "admins only"
   AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/userpass.txt
   AuthGroupFile /etc/apache2/group
   Require group admins
</Location>
```

Anyone who can improve or simplify this, please do.

Comment: You could use the `<Directory>` config of your question, no `<Location>` needed here. Any other directories should be already denied per your main `apache.conf` (`<Directory /> Require all denied ...`). I would still remove `AllowOverride All`.

Comment: Thank you Freddy, will do.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue. The [Apache documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_auth_basic.html) suggests using the `<Location />` directive instead of `<Directory />`. The following example VirtualHost should provide you with functional Basic Authentication:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName      example.com

        DocumentRoot "/srv/www/htdocs/"

        <Location />
        AuthType        Basic
        AuthName        "Authorized Access Only"
        AuthUserFile    /etc/apache2/auth/htpass
        AuthGroupFile   /etc/apache2/auth/group
        Require         group myusers
        </Location>

        <Directory "/srv/www/htdocs/">
        Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The htpass file is generated using `htpasswd -c /etc/apache2/auth/htpass myname`, the group file (which is optional!), uses the following syntax (in respect to the virtual host example above):

```
myusers: myname myfriend mycolleague
```

The htpasswd as well as group files need to be readable by the user Apache runs as.

Comment: Please remove the .htaccess file upon attempting this example, as the directives might collide.

Comment: Where is this a common issue? The [context](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/directive-dict.html#Context) for [AuthType Basic](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authn_core.html#authtype) is a directory (`<Directory>`, `<Location>`, `<Files>`...) or .htaccess context.

Comment: The sheer amount of similar posts with the same issue make it a common issue. Apache makes it difficult to get exactly right. I am aware the context suggests both are possible, however from my humble knowledge Apache changed its behavior at some point. The example I provided was copied from a working production setup.

Comment: Thanks gecko.  I'll try with Location later and report back.  Please see my comment to roaima above - is the Requite valid-user correctly overriding the higher-level Require all granted?  My htpasswd file is in the correct format and readable, though called pass.txt.  I haven't used a group file but can do if it might help.  Will probably try it.

Comment: Added a group file, restarted apache, cleared history for the page and tried a again.  Still no login prompt!  Is the higher-level "Require all granted" overriding the subfolder one?

Comment: Replaced Directory with Location. No change!

Comment: Just to confirm it's not an issue with your Apache version requiring different directives, could you attempt the same on a top level directory?

Comment: Thanks gecko.  I tried creating an admin dir under the docroot, above any domains I use.  But the pages I look for are not found.  My URLs are getting rewritten as https even if I type http - is the browser doing that and could it affect this?  I'll post the config.

Comment: I can't post  the config, it's too long for a comment.  Here's the start ```<VirtualHost *>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www/
        <Directory / >
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>```

Comment: Is there any way I can add a longer formatted chunk of code to this thread?  I can only send little chunks at a time, which get garbled.

Comment: I'm at my wit's end with this.  I now have ```<VirtualHost *>
ServerName www.example.org
DocumentRoot /var/www/example
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/example/access.log combined

<Directory "/var/www/example/" >
   Require all denied
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>``` and I can still see all pages.

Comment: @adrianhb please put updates in your question, where they can be easily seen by everyone. (You also get decent formatting and layout there.) Generally, comments are for seeking clarification, not providing it

Comment: roaima I didn't think about that - you mean edit my question with updates?  I hope my provisional answer below addresses the issue.

Answer (score 0):

in a proxy virtualbox, you may include the authentication code in  blocks.

```
<proxy *>
   AllowOverride All
   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "admins only"
   AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/userpass.txt
   AuthGroupFile /etc/apache2/group
   Require group admins
</proxy>
```

would still work.